# Change Font of MapKit Annotation Callout Title and Subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, mapkit, mkannotation

I have an `MKPointAnnotation` being added as an annotation to my `MKMapView`. I can set its `title` and `subtitle` properties but not the font for these properties' corresponding labels. Is there any way to do this without creating a custom view and adding it in `didSelectAnnotationView`? I've tried overriding `systemFontOfSize` of methods like below, but there's no reliable way to tell if I'm setting the font of the `title` or `subtitle` label.

```
@implementation UIFont (SytemFontOverride)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:20.0];
}

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15.0];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that override the `UIFont` class methods isn't a guarantee that you'll intercept font queries for the map callout, too.

I would recommend checking out the SMCalloutView project for an open source & customizable clone:

https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview

Comment: Yes, SMCalloutView is a good replacement of Callout View. But it's still needed to change the MKAnnotationView's Callout Font.